# Magento 2: Admin Action Logging Not able to Found

Tags: magento2, admin, log, action

I'm using Magento 2 Comminity Edition Version 2.1.2.

Need to configure Admin Action Logging.

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-action-log-magento-2.html

Not able to found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Admin Actions Logging` is a feature of Magento Enterprise Edition: **STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin > Admin Actions Logging**

[image]

Comment: Ahh. So how we get in Community Edition?

Comment: We should use an extension for CE version.

Comment: Only able to find this plugin : https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html which is Paid. Do u have any idea of free plugin/?

Comment: Currently, I cannot find any free extension for this feature.

Answer (score 4):

Admin action logging feature is only available for Enterprise Edition. If you wish to use this feature in community version then you can explore couple of paid plugins - 
https://marketplace.magento.com/mageaurigait-adminlogger.html
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-admin-action-log-extension.html
https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 3):

To add to Khoa's answer and where to find reporting data itself:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin** (to enable/disable available logging)
[image]

**System -> (under) Action Log -> Report** (to view logged data)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a free extension for this purpose. I was also searching for logs.

You can use composer or SSH to install it.

https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-admin-activity