# How to get user product edit logs?

Tags: magento2

Multiple users log in the system to edit product catalog, categories etc.
We need an effective system to log each users actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are many extensions available for logging admin actions, none of those are free as of now.

Also, admin logging is **`the default feature of Enterprise Edition`**, so you can either go for a paid extension or build your own version of the module in Magento 2.

If you are a developer, you can write your own custom module for logging admin users' actions with the help of free modules available for Magento 1.x.

Below is the link for Magento 1.x module which is free. You can install and test it for Magento 1.x and then with the help of its features you can write your module for Magento 2.x.

https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring

Answer (score 1):

You need **Admin Actions Logging** to identify that

Admin Actions Logging is a feature of Magento Enterprise Edition: STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin > Admin Actions Logging

Read more [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144394/magento-2-admin-action-logging-not-able-to-found)

For community version you can use below extension for to log admin action

https://amasty.com/admin-actions-log-for-magento-2.html

**There is not any other magento default way to identify your requirement.**